# 1st order ODE, IVP

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a solution to:
$$y(\ln y)'=\frac{2t}{y}.$$
So far I am unable to start the question. I was given the information that:
$$(\ln y)'=\frac{d}{dy}(\ln y).$$

Comment: That extra information is not specific to the problem.  It's just saying that the prime symbol indicates derivative.

Comment: Try to write it in the form $\frac{dy}{dt} = F(y;t)$.  Then separate variables (if the last two words mean nothing to you, review your notes).

Comment: Hi Josh! Can you please check if the information is $\frac{d}{dy}\ln(y) = \frac{y'}{y}$ or $\frac{d}{dt}\ln(y) = \frac{y'}{y}$? Thank you!

Comment: why is the $\ln$ there? can't rewrite your differential equations as the separable $\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2t}{y}?$

Answer (score 2):

Through discussion with @MatthewAllegro, I suspect you were given incorrect information. I'm guessing you should have $(\ln(y))' =\frac{d}{dt}\ln(y)$ as we want to solve $y$ as a function of $t$ such that $y=y(t)$. I imagine that information was given to encourage you to write your derivative in Leibniz notation: $$y(\ln(y))' = \frac{2t}{y} \implies y\left[\frac{d}{dt}\ln(y)\right] = \frac{2t}{y}$$ Next you should know from calculus that $\frac{d}{dt}\ln(y) = \frac{y'}{y}$ by implicit differentiation, hence $$y\left[\frac{d}{dt}\ln(y)\right] = y \cdot \frac{y'}{y} = y' = \frac{dy}{dt}$$ again using Leibniz notation. Hence $$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2t}{y}$$ This is where you now separate variables. To do this, multiply both sides by $y\cdot dt$ to get $$ydy = 2tdt$$ You now have an equation that can be integrated very easily. Can you solve for $y$ from here?

Comment: @MattAllegro New edit look okay?

Comment: Yeah, we developed it properly. But notice that your answer was anyway coherent with our common thought: $\frac{d}{dy}\ln(y)$ ...is $\frac{1}{y}$, no matter the definition given in the question. Rock!

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve equations like this one by separation of variables.

First and most important: since
$$(\ln y)'=\frac{d}{d\color{red}{t}}(\ln y)=\frac{d}{dy}(\ln y)\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{y'}{y}$$
for all $t>0$, the equation
$$y(\ln y)'=\frac{2t}{y}$$
becomes
$$y\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{2t}{y},$$
this is $yy'=2t$. You can write this as
$$y\frac{dy}{dt}=2t,$$
so $y\,dy=2t\,dt$. Now you can integrate both sides:
$$\int^{y}_{y_0}r\,dr=\int^{t}_{t_0}2s\,ds.$$
You get:
$$\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{y_0^2}{2}=2\left(\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{t_0^2}{2}\right)$$
$$y^2-c_1=2t^2-c_2$$
$$y^2=2t^2+c$$
$$y(t)=\pm\sqrt{2t^2+c},\quad c\in\mathbb{R},\quad t>0.$$